# make section fullscreen of current screen

Tags: html, css

I have five section:

```
<section id="one">Page 1</section>
<section id="two">Page 2</section>
<section id="three">Page 3</section>
<section id="four">Page 4</section>
<section id="five">Page 5</section>
```

And I want to make each of them fullscreen of current screen (i have screen 1920/1080 other has 1024/768 etc)

I have css code like this:

```
section {
display: block;
background: #CFF;
height:2000px;
padding: 60px;
padding-left: 120px;
}
```

When I change height from 2000px to 100% result is this:
[image]

Is there any idea how can I solve this problem?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hx7cuh96/)

**EDIT**

I've found a nice article about that. [see here if anyone will need it](http://stanislav.it/how-to-make-div-element-100-height-of-browser-window-using-css-only/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implicitly set the dimensions of the document (`body`) to those of the viewport (`html`), then give a height and width of 100% to each section- which is then calculated relative to this.

Change your CSS for `body` and `section` to:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/hx7cuh96/7/)

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
}

section {
    display: block;
    background: #CFF;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding: 60px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

By adding `box-sizing:border-box;` to the CSS for `section`, each section will maintain 100% width inclusive of the applied padding.

### **Note**

You can also [**viewport percentage units**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths), namely use `vh` and `vw` (viewport height) and (viewport width) units to cause content to stretch to fill a proportionate amount of the viewport, where 100 = 100%. This is likely the preferred solution vs implicit % units, [depending on your required browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) and does not require the element to be nested within a parent with explicit height/width settings

Comment: This will work only if the `<section>` tag is direct ancestor of `<body>` tag. If for example you have a `<div>` containing all your sections you must set its `height` and `width` to 100% as well.

Answer (score 6):

Just use:

```
section {
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

No need to set `height` and `width` properties for `<body>` and `<html>` tags.

Comment: while this works, it resizes the section whenever the viewport width/height changes, causing UI quirks, it is better to set the body and HTML properties and then use min-height:100% on the section

Answer (score 1):

Set the height on the body and html elements to 100%, then use height:100% on the sections.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hx7cuh96/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the document's height to the size of the browser viewport before you can give it's children a height in percents:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height:100%
}
```

Then, just give the sections  a height of 100%:

```
section {
    display: block;
    background: #CFF;
    height:100%;
    padding: 60px;
    padding-left: 120px;
}
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/hx7cuh96/2/)

Answer (score 1):

That isn't too hard to do.

What you need to do is give the `body` and the `html` a height as well. I changed the following CSS:

```
html {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    section {
        display: block;
        background: #CFF;
        height:100%;
        padding: 60px;
        padding-left: 120px;
    }
```

You can see how it works in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koedood/hx7cuh96/1/)